# Java BigInteger prime numbers

Tags: java, primes, biginteger

I am trying to generate a random prime number of type BigInteger, that is between a min and max value which I supply.

I am aware of the BigInteger.probablePrime(int bitlength, random), but I am not sure how or even if the bitlength translates into a max/min value of the outputted prime.

Thanks,
Steven1350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BigInteger.probablePrime(bitLength, random)` is going to return a (probable) prime of the specified bit length.  That translates into a maximum value of 2^bitlength - 1 and a minimum of 2^(bitlength - 1).  As much as I hate it as an answer, it's probably your best bet unless you want to start delving into number theory.

What you would have to do is figure out the bit lengths that your range calls for, then pass them to `probablePrime()` until you get back a prime that's in the right range.

Comment: Interesting. From the Doc, "the probability that the returned BI is composite is < 2^-100", pretty unlikely indeed! Would you know by chance the complexity of this method?

Comment: Instead of invoking probalePrime with a bitlength the range calls for one could create a random big integer in the range and invoke nextProbablePrime on it. This will generate the prime number faster as invoking problePrime multiple times. Of cours you will have to tackle the situation where the reult is bigger than the max value of your range.

Answer (score 3):

jprete's answer is fine if your ratio max/min is not close to 1.

If you have a narrow range, your best bet is probably just to do something like the following:

```
// this is pseudocode:
//
// round min down to multiple of 6, max up to multiple of 6
min6 = floor(min/6);
max6 = ceil(max/6);
maybePrimeModuli = [1,5];
do 
{
   b = generateRandom(maybePrimeModuli.length);
   // generate a random offset modulo 6 which could be prime
   x = 6*(min6 + generateRandom(max6-min6)) + b;
   // generate a random number which is congruent to b modulo 6
   // from 6*min6 to 6*max6-1
   // (of the form 6k+1 or 6k+5)

   // the other choices 6k, 6k+2, 6k+3, 6k+4 are composite 
} while not isProbablePrime(x);
```

The [density of primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Table_of_.CF.80.28x.29.2C_x_.2F_ln_x.2C_and_li.28x.29) is fairly high overall, it's basically 1 in log(x), so you shouldn't have to repeat too many times to find a prime number. (just as an example: for numbers around 10<sup>23</sup>, one in every 52 integers on average is a prime number. The above code only bothers with 2 out of every 6 numbers, so you'd end up looping an average of 17 times for numbers around 10<sup>23</sup>.)

Just make sure you have a good primality test, and the Java BigInteger has one.

As an exercise for the reader, extend the above function so it filters out more composite numbers ahead of time by using 30k + x (modulo 30, there are 22 moduli that are always composite, only 8 remaining that could be prime), or 210k + x.

edit: see also [US patent #7149763](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/7149763.html) (OMFG!!!)

Comment: Do you need to add min2 to x?

Comment: Er...you probably want to flip the while-loop termination too...missed that one before.  Other than that I think you're clear.

Comment: doh, i'm having a bad day :-)

Comment: the math is willing, but the fleshing out is weak