# Improve algorithm to calculate prime factor decomposition

Tags: java, algorithm, math

We are doing the following programming exercise: [Primes in numbers](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54d512e62a5e54c96200019e).

The task is to calculate the prime factor decomposition of a positive number.

First we have written:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class PrimeDecomp {
    public static String factors(int n) {
      System.out.println("\n\\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn: "+n);
      Map<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();


      for(int i=1; n>1 && i<(n/2); i=1){
        System.out.println("out i: "+i);
        int prime = nextPrime(i);
        System.out.println("out prime: "+prime);
        while(n%prime!=0){
          i=prime;
          System.out.println("in i: "+i);
          prime = nextPrime(i);  
          System.out.println("in prime: "+prime);
        }
        n=n/prime;
        int count = map.containsKey(prime) ? map.get(prime) : 0;
        map.put(prime, count+1);
        System.out.println("map: "+map);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\nnew n: "+n);
      }

      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
        String text = entry.getValue()>1 ? String.format("(%d**%d)",entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()) : String.format("(%d)",entry.getKey());
        result.append(text);      
      }
      System.out.println("result: "+result);

      return result.toString();
    }

    public static int nextPrime(int n){
      BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
      return Integer.parseInt(b.nextProbablePrime().toString());
    }

}
```

When we test the previous code with n = 35791357, it runs out of time (the execution is above 16000 ms)

We decided to use another approach, and instead of iterating to calculate each time the primes, we calculate them all at once up to n, as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class PrimeDecomp {
    public static String factors(int n) {
      //System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn: "+n+"\n");
      Map<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
      List<Integer> primes = sieveOfEratosthenes(n);
      //System.out.println("primes: "+primes);

      for(int i=0; n>1 && i<(n/2); i=0){
        //System.out.println("out i: "+i);
        int prime = primes.get(i);
        //System.out.println("out prime: "+prime);
        while(n%prime!=0){
          prime = primes.get(++i);  
          //System.out.println("in i: "+i);
          //System.out.println("in prime: "+prime);
        }
        n=n/prime;
        int count = map.containsKey(prime) ? map.get(prime) : 0;
        map.put(prime, count+1);
        //System.out.println("map: "+map);
        //System.out.println("\n\n\n\nnew n: "+n);
      }

      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
        String text = entry.getValue()>1 ? String.format("(%d**%d)",entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()) : String.format("(%d)",entry.getKey());
        result.append(text);      
      }
      System.out.println("result: "+result);

      return result.toString();
    }

    public static List<Integer> sieveOfEratosthenes(int n){
      boolean prime[] = new boolean[n+1];
      Arrays.fill(prime,true);
      for(int p=2; p*p<=n; p++){
        if(prime[p]){
          for(int i=p*2; i<=n; i+=p){
            prime[i]=false;
          }
        }
      }
      List<Integer> primeNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
      for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
        if(prime[i]){
          primeNumbers.add(i);
        }
      }
      return primeNumbers;
    }

}
```

After testing the new code, we observe that when n = 933555431, the execution times out.

We thought about caching the primes calculated in the previous execution, so then the algorithm would only need to calculate the primes between the previous execution and the new n.

It could be explained in pseudocode as:

```
cachedPrimes = Create a static list to hold the calculated primes
primesCalculated = Create a static int to save until what n primes have been calculated

if primesCalculated < n
 cachedPrimes = Get the primes list from primesCalculated to n
 primesCalculated = n
```

We started to draft the code as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class PrimeDecomp {

    static List<Integer> cachedPrimes = new ArrayList<>();
    static int primesCalculated = 0;

    public static String factors(int n) {
      //System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn: "+n+"\n");
      Map<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
      List<Integer> primes = cachedPrimes;


      if(primesCalculated<n){
        if(primesCalculated==0){
          primes.addAll(sieveOfEratosthenes(2,n));
        }else{
          int diff = n - primesCalculated;
          primes.addAll(sieveOfEratosthenes(diff,n));
        }
        cachedPrimes = new ArrayList<Integer>(primes);
        primesCalculated = n;
      }

      //System.out.println("primes: "+primes);

      for(int i=0; i < primes.size() && n>1; i=0){
        //System.out.println("out i: "+i);
        int prime = primes.get(i);
        //System.out.println("out prime: "+prime);
        while(i < primes.size()-1 && n%prime!=0){
          prime = primes.get(++i);  
          //System.out.println("in i: "+i);
          //System.out.println("in prime: "+prime);
        }
        n=n/prime;
        int count = map.containsKey(prime) ? map.get(prime) : 0;
        map.put(prime, count+1);
        //System.out.println("map: "+map);
        //System.out.println("\n\n\n\nnew n: "+n);
      }

      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
        String text = entry.getValue()>1 ? String.format("(%d**%d)",entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()) : String.format("(%d)",entry.getKey());
        result.append(text);      
      }
      //System.out.println("result: "+result);

      return result.toString();
    }

    public static List<Integer> sieveOfEratosthenes(int from, int to){
      boolean prime[] = new boolean[to+1];
      Arrays.fill(prime,true);
      for(int p=from; p*p<=to; p++){
        if(prime[p]){
          for(int i=p*2; i<=to; i+=p){
            prime[i]=false;
          }
        }
      }
      List<Integer> primeNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
      for(int i=from; i<=to; i++){
        if(prime[i]){
          primeNumbers.add(i);
        }
      }
      return primeNumbers;
    }

}
```

We are having difficulties trying to understand the code behaviour. When we execute the exercise's tests we see:

"expected: 61140377" but was: 933555431"

[image]

If we execute it manually as follows, with n=61140377, it pass:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.*;

public class PrimeDecompTest { 
    @Test
    public void testPrimeDecompOne() {
        int lst = 7775460;        
        assertEquals(
            "(2**2)(3**3)(5)(7)(11**2)(17)",
            PrimeDecomp.factors(lst));

            lst = 61140377;        
        assertEquals(
            "(61140377)",
            PrimeDecomp.factors(lst));


    }

}
```

We think this is due to the static cachedPrimes list. How could we improve the code to shorten its execution time and pass the tests?

We have read:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-generate-prime-numbers
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-ways-to-check-for-prime-and-find-next-prime-in-java/
- [Java BigInteger prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801003/java-biginteger-prime-numbers)
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_probableprime.htm
- [Converting from Integer, to BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878192/converting-from-integer-to-biginteger)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-subtract-method-in-java-with-examples/
- [Most efficient way to increment a Map value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81346/most-efficient-way-to-increment-a-map-value-in-java)
- [Converting from Integer, to BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878192/converting-from-integer-to-biginteger)
- [How to sort Map values by key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java)
- [How do I efficiently iterate over each entry in a Java Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map)
- [Optimal way to find next prime number (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407251/optimal-way-to-find-next-prime-number-java)
- [How do I join two lists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-clone-a-list-in-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following fact:

If `n` is not prime, then it has a divisor `d` such that `d*d <= n`.

```
for (int divisor = 2; n > 1; ++divisor) {
    if (divisor * divisor >= n) {
        // n is prime, we have n**1 here
        break;
    }
    if (n % divisor == 0) {
        // divisor is a prime factor, divide n by it while we can
        int cnt = 0;
        while (n % divisor == 0) {
            n /= divisor;
            ++cnt;
        }
        // we have divisor**cnt here
    }
}
```

update: the complexity of this algorithm is `O(sqrt (n))`

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [github.com/TilmanNeumann/java-math-library](https://github.com/TilmanNeumann/java-math-library) for more sophisticated integer factorization algorithms.